# Golang: How to generate random float using only crypto/rand

Tags: go, security, random

I'm using gosec to check if my code has any security flaws. But it is reporting the use of math/rand (Use of weak random number generator (math/rand instead of crypto/rand)) pkg in this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    a := rand.Float64()
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

The problem is: crypto/rand does not have the option to get a random float: https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/rand
How can I do that?

Comment: Why can't you use the methods in `math/rand` to convert the crypto source to a float? You can also just look at how it's implemented in `math/rand` if you want to learn for yourself how it's done.

Comment: gosec reports if I use math/rand. I want to use just crypto/rand

Comment: You are free to copy the methods from `math/rand` to wrap a `crypto/rand` source, but I fail to see how that would be more secure. Are you certain `gosec` flags the use if you use a secure source?

Comment: gosec reports a false positive here. Use math/rand.

Comment: @Volker, @Vivi: I just tried gosec with `math/rand` using `crypto/rand`
, and it reported no issues.

Comment: See the answer here for an example of using `crypto/rand` as a source for `math/rand`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965044/using-crypto-rand-for-generating-permutations-with-rand-perm/40976463